# Optimal ThreadPoolSize for Spring Services

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I am writing a Spring Service which makes N calls to another service stitches the response and returns it to the client. I am thinking that I should make the N calls in parallel and once they all finish I can stitch the response.

I am creating a new FixedThreadPoolExecutor where I want to submit one thread for each of the N. I am hearing advice that the number of threads should be:

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1)
```

Would this be the case in this scenario. The majority of time in my app is waiting for the service I am calling to respond for each of the items.

Right now I was using new CachedThreadPool and clearly that was the wrong choice since I am noticing my threads are in the tens of thousands. I am running on machines with this spec:

CPU Reserve (in mCores*) *1000 mCores = 1 Amazon vCPU = 1/2 physical core
: 200

CPU Throttle Threshold (in Cores)
: 2

Memory Reserve (GB) : 1

Memory Throttle Threshold (GB) : 2

Comment: Unfortunately it is not that easy. Depending on your OS (version), these methods can return kinda different numbers. You could search the javaspecialist.eu newsletter archive. The question on how many threads to pool is discussed there multiple times in depth.